# Как изменить вид (код) нового класса по умолчанию в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

По умолчанию код при создании нового класса в IntelliJ IDEA выглядит так:

```
package packagename;

public class classname {
}
```

Хочу добавить перед первой строкой комментарий по-умолчанию. Помогите, пожалуйста понять, как это сделать.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходишь в `Idea` --> `Ctrl + Alt + S` --> раздел `Editor` --> раздел `File and Code Templates` --> в небольшой вкладке увидишь файлы, находишь файл с `Class` --> далее откроет следующий код:

```java
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} {
}
```

В этот код между строк пишешь свой комментарий. Например:

```java
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: John.Smith
 * Date: 6/1/11
 * Time: 12:54 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File and Code Templates.
 */
public class ${NAME} {
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Рылся Editor, но немного не там...

Comment: А не подскажете, где там настройки первоначального положения курсора?